# Lowering memory usage in HashMap in Rust

Tags: memory, hashmap, rust

I'm trying to parse a very long file by using a fixed-size sliding window over it. For each such window I'd like to either insert it to a `HashMap` as the key with custom struct as value, or modify existing value for the window. My main problem is memory usage, since it should scale into very large quantities (up to several billions of distinct windows) and I want to reuse existing keys.

I would like to append windows (or more specifically bytes) to a vector and use the index as a key in the `HashMap`, but use the window under index for hash computation and key comparison. Because windows are overlapping, I will append only the part of the window which is new (if I have an input AAAB and size 3 I would have 2 windows: AAA and AAB, but would only store 4 bytes - AAAB; windows would have indices 0 and 1 respectively), which is the reason behind not keying the HM with window itself.

Here's the simplified pseudo-code, in which I omitted the minimal-input problem:

```
let file =  // content of the file on which i can call windows()
let vec = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::new()));  // RefCell allows me to store Rc in the hashmap while mutating the underlying vector
let hm: HashMap<KeyStruct, ValueStruct> = HashMap::new();
for i in file.windows(FIXED_SIZE) {
    let idx = vec.len();
    vec.borrow_mut().push(i);
    if hm.contains_key(KeyStruct::new(idx)) {
        // get the key associated with i
        // modify the value associated with i
        // do something with the key
        vec.borrow_mut().pop();  // window is already in the vector
    }
    else {
        hm.insert(KeyStruct::new(idx), ValueStruct::new(...));
    }
}
```

I have came up with 2 different approaches: either modifying the existing `HashMap` implementation so that it works as intended, or using a custom struct as key to the `HashMap`. Since I would only use one vector in order to store windows, I could store a `Rc` to it in the `HashMap` and then use that for lookups.

I could also create a struct which would hold both a `Rc` and index, using it as a key to the `HashMap`. The latter solution works with a vanilla `HashMap`, but stores a lot of redundant `Rc`s to the same vector. I also thought about storing a static pointer to `Rc` and then get `Rc` in `unsafe` blocks, but I would have to guarantee that the position of the `Rc` on the stack never changes and I'm not sure if I can guarantee that.

I tried to implement the first approach (custom `HashMap`), but it turns out that `Bucket`s use a lot of features which are gated, and I can't compile the project using the stable compiler.

What's even worse is that I would like to get the key that is already in the `HashMap` on a successful lookup (because different indices can store the same window, for which the `hash`/`cmp` would be identical) and use it inside the value structure. I couldn't find a way to do this using the provided API for `HashMap` - the closest I get is by using `entry()`, which can contain an `OccupiedEntry`, but it doesn't have any way to retrieve the key, and there's no way to get it by unsafe memory lookups, because documentation on `repr()` says that the order in structs is not guaranteed in the default representation. I can store the key (or only the index) in the value struct, but that adds yet another `size_of::<usize>()` bytes per entry, only to store the index/key in a reachable manner, which is kept with that entry either way.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to compile/reuse parts of std::collections which are not pub, such that I could modify few methods of `HashMap` and compile the whole project?
- Is there any way of getting the key after successful lookup in the `HashMap`? (I even [found out](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1194#issuecomment-130482818) that libs team decided against implementing method over `Entry` which would allow me to get the key...)
- Can you see any alternative to solutions that I mentioned?

**EDIT**

To clarify the problem let's consider a simple example - input ABABCBACBC and window size of 2.  *We should give index as a key to the `HashMap`, and it should get the window-size number of bytes as window starting from that index: with vector [A, A, C], index 1 and window-size 2 `HashMap` should try to find a hash/key for AC.*

We get windows like this:

```
AB -> BA -> AB -> BC -> CB -> BA -> AC -> CB -> BC
```

First pair is AB, we append it into the empty vector and give it an index of 0.

```
vec = [A, B]
hm = [(0, val)]
```

The next pair is BA:

1. start with vec = [A, B]
2. using algorithm not shown here, I know that I have a common part between last inserted window (AB) and current window (BA), namely B
3. append part of the window to the existing vector, so we have vec = [A, B, A]
4. perform a lookup using index 1 as the index of window
5. it has not been found so the new key, val is inserted to `HashMap`

vec = [A, B, A]
hm = [(0, val0), (1, val1)]

Next up is window AB:

1. once again we have a common part - A
2. append: vec = [A, B, A, B]
3. lookup using index 2
4. it is successful, so I should delete the newly inserted part of window and get the index of the window inside vector - in this case 0
5. modify value, do something with the key etc...

   vec = [A, B, A]
   hm = [(0, val0_modified), (1, val1)]

After looping over this input i should end up with:

```
vec = [A, B, A, B, C, B, A, C]
```

and indices for pairs could be represented as: [(AB, 0), (BA, 1), (BC, 3), (CB, 4), (AC, 6)]

I **do not** want to modify keys. I also don't want to modify the vector with the exception of pushing/popping the window during lookup/insertion.

Sidenote: even though I still have redundant information in this particular example after putting everything into vector, it won't be the case while working with the original data.

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand what you were attempting to do (I can see you thought quite a lot about it, but unfortunately your attempts at solution clutter the explanation somewhat). Would it possible to show an example of what you want to do using an array of key-values and a few "rounds" of the loop? Are you trying to *modify* the keys?

Comment: Re #2: Rust Nightly includes an unstable `key` method on `OccupiedEntry`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/hash_map/struct.OccupiedEntry.html

Comment: @Dogbert: Beware. I am afraid that Fuine is attempting to modify the keys, which would be a very bad idea...

Comment: Is there a reason you do not have a hashmap `{ "AB" => val0, "BC" => val1, ...}` and instead use this vector look-aside?

Comment: I reuse the keys quite a lot in the value structs, and as i mentioned above keeping an int yields smaller memory overheads than keeping and reusing a window of size 50-100 (that's roughly 50 + 24 bytes per one key usage as opposed to 8 bytes for usize on 64 bit machine (or 16 if i would go with Rc + idx struct). The solution should really scale up.

Comment: How about additional `HashMap<u64, usize>`, where `key` is just a subsring hash of some kind, and value is the index in `vec`?

Comment: @swizard It is an option, but it requires 2 lookups for each window and it has an overhead of roughly 24 bytes per window (calculated_hash + hash_hashmap + idx). I might consider it, although i think that it's worse than Rc + idx as key struct. I know I'm being very picky, but this problem requires really well-thought solution.

Comment: [One question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829), please.